# How Can I Iterate over JavaScript array containing single character strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ascii, transformation

I am attempting to solve what should be a relatively easy practice problem in JavaScript. The object is to create a function called `shiftLetters()` that does the following:

1. Converts a string passed as a parameter to a string array comprised of the single letters within the string.
2. Use the `Array.prototype.map()` method to iterate over each single character in the array.
3. If the character is a space, it should not be transformed.
4. If the character is alphanumeric, it should be transformed using `String.charCodeAt()` by advancing one character forward (e.g., F becomes G, f becomes g).
5. Using `String.fromCharCode()`, assemble a string such that, for example, 'I cannot tell a lie' is transformed to 'J dboopu ufmm b mjf.'

Here is my code so far:

```
var shiftLetters = function(string){
  // 1. Convert string to an array of characters.
  const stringArray = string.split('');
  const mappedString = stringArray.map( (char) => {
    for (char in mappedString) {
      // TO BE DONE
    }
  });
}

const example = 'Able was I ere I saw Elba.';
```

I see the following problems with the above code and I am not sure how to resolve them:

- Though the string—in this sample, 'Able was I ere I saw Elba.'—is transformed successfully into an array comprised of single characters, e.g. `['A', 'b', 'l', 'e'...]`, `String.prototype.charCodeAt()` and `String.fromCharCode()` are not methods exposed by arrays and cannot be used in that context.
- In searches on MDN and other online resources, I have been unable to uncover any available methods that can reference an index within an array and get the ASCII character code for that element.

Though I can see that if I *did* successfully create a transformed array of characters, it would then be a simple matter to employ ```Array.prototype.join()`` to create a string transformed in the way described above. I just haven't been able to figure out how to get to that point.

I would appreciate any insights that can be offered. In the meantime, I will continue my research. If I find the answer, I will post it here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sincerely,

Robert Hieger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the char code, add one and get the new character.

```js
const
    shiftLetters = string => string
        .split('')
        .map(c => c === ' ' || !/[a-z\d]/i.test(c)
            ? c
            : String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1))
        .join(''),
    example = 'Able was I ere I saw Elba.';

console.log(shiftLetters(example));
```

Comment: Thank you, Nina, for this chained implementation. I tested this code, and of course, it worked. As it turns out, the only thing that prevented my code from running correctly was that I neglected to placed the square brackets around the regular expression suggested by Danilo above.

I do appreciate the elegance and succinctness, however, of the chained implementation you suggest, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the for loop inside the `map`: you are already iterating over the characters in StringArray. Since the characters are strings, you can use all string methods on them. In this case, you'd need `String.fromCharCode` and `String.charCodeAt`.

```
var shiftLetters = function(string){
  // 1. Convert string to an array of characters.
  const stringArray = string.split('');
  const transformedStringArray = stringArray.map( (char) => {
    if (/[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(char)){
      return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1);
    } 
    else {
      return char;
    }
  })
  return transformedStringArray.join('');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Danilo for your thoughtful and swift response. Unfortunately, when I attempt to log the result of this function to the console. the output is```undefined```. I will continue searching for the cause of this problem. Your response has definitely brought me closer to the answer, however.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss a return statement somewhere? I set up a [repl](https://repl.it/@daniloxxv/OpulentMediumorchidSet#index.js) and with that code and got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as concise as it gets without being too hard to follow

```
var shiftLetters = string => (
    string.split('').map( c => (
        String.fromCharCode( c.charCodeAt(0) + !!c.match(/[A-Za-z\d]/) )
    )).join("")
);
```

Note that I am using implicit returns, hence the lack of an explicit return statement. The trickiest part of this solution is the line

```
c.charCodeAt(0) + !!c.match(/[A-Za-z\d]/)
```

In this, we check to see if c is a purely alphanumeric character with `match`. If it is, `match` will return a `Match` object, otherwise we get null. Then, `!!` will convert truthy/falsey (Match Obj vs. Null) values into a boolean. Finally, when doing arithmetic with booleans in JavaScript, false = 0 and true = 1. So this statement will map each alphanumeric character to the next one, and map all other characters to themselves.